# Git rebase process gets stuck with detached head

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying on a certain project to reword the penultimate commit to fix a typo by running `git rebase -i HEAD~3`, (using the "nano" editor) then changing the default `pick` option of that commit to `r` or `reword` (on the initial rebase file window), and, without modifying anything else. I'm doing it on the `master` branch, if useful.

As soon as I save the file, Git, instead of showing me the next rebase window to pick a new name for that commit as usual, it puts itself and informs me of a detached HEAD state with that commit, that is also shown upon `git status` command from then on, until I type `git checkout master`.

No matter how many times I try, the same thing happens.

Additional note: I had previously changed the used editor to "nano" by running the single command: `git config --global core.editor nano`

EDIT: As requested, this is the message that Git gives me when I save the TODO list:

> adrian$ git rebase -i HEAD~1
>
> Note: checking out 'da91bbcedc78cb2ebcaa9dc51f38c8d0a550195d'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
>   changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
>   state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
>   do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
>
> git checkout -b
>
> HEAD is now at da91bbc... Test message
>
> This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout.
>   could not detach HEAD

Output after running `git rebase --continue` at this point:

> No rebase in progress?

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, because rebasing should not be putting you into a detached HEAD state. Are you sure you included _every_ step you took while rebasing?  This has never happened to me in 6 years of using Git.

Comment: I'm sure. The only possible mistake I didn't mention because I didn't consider, is that on few attempts of this process I had written a new commit text on the initial window (where you first have to switch to the `r` or `reword` option) caused by wrong intuition impulses. Perhaps this caused the issued to be triggered from then on.

Comment: In my experience, starting the rebase will apply commits, and for each commit, the bash will popup an emacs with the original commit.  I can choose to edit that message or not.  In any case, once I _save_ and exit, the rebase continues.  Did you save the commit message before exiting?

Comment: Your editor might not return with status 0, for example. Or you might have a merge commit within a range.

Comment: did you try to use `e` instead or `r`, execute `git commit --amend`, change the title, then `git rebase --continue` ?

Comment: Tim, If I understand you right, with "for each commit, the bash will popup an emacs" you refer to the sequential windows that prompt one-by-one for each commit you have indicated the desire to alter in the initial rebase window. My problem is I'm not even prompted with the effective window to rewrite the commit description, since as soon as I save the initial commit options window, the rebase process stops with that detached HEAD state. Therefore I can't even opt to save the commit message regarding to your question.

Comment: Does it really not show any error messages? What about `git rebase --continue`?

Comment: Please update your question with a copy-and-paste of the exact message that git gives after you edit the TODO list and exit the editor.  If a rebase leaves you in a detached state, that usually means it stopped midway through for some reason and needs you to tell it what to do; and the message it gives is usually a pretty explicit prompt for what things you can do next.

Comment: Edited my original question

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen _“You must be doing something wrong, because rebasing should not be putting you into a detached HEAD state.”_ This message normally appears when you choose `edit` in the interactive rebase to-do.

Comment: I guess you made the checkout without giving the remote repository. That's how you end up in detached head.

Comment: @Melebius I didn't actually know this, though I have spent a ton of time thinking about rebasing.  Maybe you should post an answer to resolve all these doubts.

Comment: @Melebius Actually, it makes perfect sense if you think about it, because while editing the commit technically there is no head.

Comment: Did you get the lfs error without using lfs to track a type of file?

Comment: It looks so many people are facing the same problem :)

Comment: I am using Vim instead of nano like you and facing the same problem. So I don't think  changing the used editor you did causing the problem. Further more , I do the same effort and got the same phenomenon like you. Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The detached HEAD message appears normally when you put `edit` in the to-do file for the interactive rebase. You must have mistakenly put `edit` there instead of `reword`. Or Git might have entered this mode (which is also entered in conflicts) due to the error found in your output:

> This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout. could not detach HEAD

You should resolve this error before continuing. Git tells you what to do.

The `edit` mode allows modifying the commit message like `reword` mode but also the file contents. Therefore Git left you in a state where you can commit changes and then continue rebasing using `git rebase --continue`.

## Editing the commit message (like `reword`) in the `edit` mode

When you want to just edit the commit message and continue rebasing, run

```
git commit --amend
```

which opens the editor to let you edit the commit message. After you have finished, run

```
git rebase --continue
```

## Leaving unfinished rebase

> As soon as I save the file, Git, instead of showing me the next rebase window to pick a new name for that commit as usual, it puts itself and informs me of a detached HEAD state with that commit, that is also shown upon `git status` command from then on, until I type `git checkout master`.

This is not the correct way of leaving unfinished rebase, you should use

```
git rebase --abort
```

instead.

Comment: Doing what Git told me (removing the file .git/hooks/post-checkout), and then another action it said (removing the other file .git/hooks/pre-push) solved the problem. I just couldn't see the relation of these Git LFS (Large File Support) messages with the rebase failing. As a side note answering you, no, I wasn't entering the `e` option wrongly, and I always proceed with `git rebase --abort`, but this problem was simply vanishing the rebase, thus these related commands did not work. Thanks!

Comment: `fatal: No rebase in progress?`

Comment: @leonheess I am sorry but your comment is not descriptive enough to understand what it is related to. If you’ve got a new problem, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thank you for offer the correct way to leaving unfinished rebase. It remind me!

Comment: Not excectly solve my problem. As I said, just a little teeny-tiny remind me. For the stackoverflow more substantial, I'm sorry that I can't. :)

Answer (score 11):

I had this same issue with `git rebase -i`, with the same exact output and absolutely no indication of why from git.

Through trial and error, I eventually found that my post-checkout hook (**repodir**/.git/hooks/post-checkout) was exiting with a non-zero status.  Once I added an `exit 0` to the end of it, the rebase succeeded without leaving the repo in the detached HEAD state.

Comment: Were you explicitly using lfs in .gitattributes? I want to know if it triggers the error even if you aren't using it

Comment: I was not explicitly using lfs in .gitattributes, no.

Comment: Failing hooks caused this issue for me, too. I used `git rev-parse --git-dir` to find the `.git` directory and files underneath it, but that doesn't work when using `git worktree` (it gives the `.git` file, which tells where to find a directory-like structure). Switching to `git rev-parse --git-common-dir` did the trick

Comment: Yes, no any indication of why from git , it's horrible

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem when doing rebase squash. I am not found the reason about this .

My workaround is copy this master branch happening this problem to other new branch let's say branch "tiantale".

When I do the same rebase steps in new "tiantale" branch,It works fine.

Then I do cherry-pick to pick this commit created by rebase to master branch.